# Chess Match Neustadtl-Porges 1901 Prague

Tags: database, famous-games

Where can I get the full list of moves in the match between Hermann Neustadtl and Moritz Porges played in Prague in 1901?

I want the moves from the whole match, not just the famous endgame analysis.

Comment: I cannot find this game on the usual databases, which means we have to hope for it to figure in some old publications. Can you give us a link to "the famous endgame analysis" ?

Comment: @Evargalo  probably he was referring to [this](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessplayer?pid=31262&kpage=1#reply6)

Comment: I am unable to locate this game in a database of ~23 Million games. I have 4 games they played in Prague in 1884 , but none for 1901. A few online databases scans , also indicates there are no recorded games , I am actually unsure that the position / analysis you refer to is actually from their game tbh.

Comment: I have the analysis from British chess Magazine 1907 of the well known endgame study and I wanted to find the list of moves for the entire match.

Comment: @Dheebs assuming you are using chessbase are you able to search this position. Would be interesting to see what comes up

Comment: i dont get anything for that position either.  what is interesting is that from what i can see the position is actually starting with the white king on e4 instead of e3. @GFB Do you have the clipping from the BCM 21?

Comment: The position starts with White's king on e3. The position is published in several endgame study books. In 2021 or 2022 Grandmaster Karsten Muller has analyzed the position using Stockfish and has found it to be a draw